# In this function (in C) that takes an integer as an argument: Why isn't sum = 0 every time the function is called?

Tags: c, function, static

Update: Hi, I did not misunderstood the goal of the function. I was just surprised that static int sum = 0 does not execute each time the function is called, so I don't understand that. The goal of the function is correct: to sum the values and give the final value, and it works fine. The question is: Why isn't the sum changing into 0 each time the function is called? I suppose that's how it is set up by convention? That since I put static int sum, it will run only once and make it equal to zero, but then it won't run this line of the code again when the function is called? 
In the following code, the only way I could make this function work was when I declared that sum = 0.

---

I was expecting the output to be 55, 45, 50, since sum is getting value 0 each time it is run! But for some reason, after the second time the function is called, the first line "static int sum = 0;" is skipped. Why? Thanks a lot =)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum (int num)
{
    static int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + num;
    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
   printf("%d ",sum(55));
   printf("%d ",sum(45));
   printf("%d ",sum(50));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because of the `static` keyword. This makes the variable behave like it is a global variable... almost. The lifetime of the variable is like a global variable, while the visibility (scope) is local to the function

Comment: Because it's `static`. It gets the initial value when the program starts (before `main()` is called) and keeps the same value (possibly changed inside the function) between invocations of the function.

Comment: It should make no difference in the example, since `static int sum = 0` is **only initialised once** but would be initialised to `0` anyway.

Comment: Totally mystified why you want a function that is called `sum` to *not* sum the value but just return the same value you passed it.

Comment: Hi Guys, I did not misunderstood the goal of the function. I was just surprised that static int sum = 0 does not execute each time the function is called, so I don't understand that. The goal of the function is correct: to sum the values and give the final value, and it works fine. The question is: Why isn't the sum changing into 0 each time the function is called? I suppose that's how it is set up by convention? That since I put static int sum, it will run only once and make it equal to zero, but then it won't run this line of the code again when the function is called?

Answer (score 2):

> Since `sum` (variable) is getting value `0` each time it (`sum` function) is run!

No, it's not.

> But for some reason, after the second time the function is called, the first line `static int sum = 0;` is skipped. Why?

It is not skipped. That is just your impression. But the initialization of `0` happens only once prior to program startup.

> If the function is called everytime there's a call to `sum()`, why doesn't `sum` (variable) gets the value of `0`, since it is written in the beginning of the function?

Because `sum` is qualified with the `static` storage class specifier, which means that the `sum` variable is not destroyed after the function has been executed once and it retains its value for the whole entire program execution.

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier_Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier static, has static storage duration. **Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup**.
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §6.2.4/3

---

Omit `static` at the `sum` variable and you get your desired result.

Note that the purpose of the `sum` function is pretty useless in that way. I guess it is just for testing purpose only.

---

#### EDIT:

For me it seems that you actually got the function from somewhere else and misunderstood the purpose of the program and the function `sum`.

The original purpose of the function `sum` is to sum the input values provided at different function calls to `sum()` and return the current sum at each function call.

That is the reason, why `sum` (variable) is qualified with `static` (to retain its value).

The purpose is not to just pass the input value through, which is what think the purpose of `sum()` is.

Comment: What is the "desired result"? Without remembering the previous `sum` the function has no apparent purpose.

Comment: @WeatherVane It indeed got no logical purpose. I guess OP just confused the meaning of `static` in that context. AFAIU OP wants just to print the input value of `sum` (function).

Comment: But even so, `sum` will be initialised to `0` anyway, making the question even more strange. It makes no sense. The OP's claim that it "only works when set to `0`" can't be true.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is a mess of strange things going on here. The only thing we know is OP wants to output the same value which came in. The `sum` variable is just a "placeholder".

Comment: @WeatherVane "*the only way I could make this function work was when I declared that `sum = 0`*" is indeed true. But emphasis lies on the omission of `static`, not the `0` initialization.

Comment: @WeatherVane I finally got it. I*m certain the OP confused the purpose of the program. That's why we all was confused so much, why s/he wants that output. I took that into an edit.

Comment: I was tempted yesterday to edit the question to make clear what the difference in the code was, but had the uneasy feeling that would be incorrect.